# Convergence for complex series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Suppose that for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ $(a_{m,n})_m$ is a sequence of positive real numbers such that 
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m,n}=C<\infty,$$
 and that $(a_{m})_m$ is another sequence of positive real numbers such that $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m}=C.$$

Suppose also that for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $a_{m,n}\to a_m.$ Is it true that

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m,n}e^{itm}\to\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_{m}e^{itm},$$
for all $t\in\mathbb{R}?$

Answer (score 0):

If you add another constraint: $a_{m,n}\le a_m$ for sufficiently large $m,n$, then the limit you hypothesized is true.

Let us assume $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{m,n}=a_m$.

Then,
$$\begin{align}
\lim_n\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_{m,n}e^{itm}
&=\lim_n\int a_{m,n}e^{itm}d\mu \qquad{(1)}\\
&=\int \lim_n a_{m,n}e^{itm}d\mu \qquad{(2)}\\
&=\int a_m e^{itm} d\mu \\
&=\sum^\infty_{m=0}a_m e^{itm}
\end{align}$$

$(1):$ writing a sum as a Lebesgue integral with respect to the counting measure on $\mathbb N$.

$(2):$ exchanging limit and integration as permitted by dominated convergence theorem, since $|a_{m,n}e^{itm}|\le a_m$ and $\int a_m d\mu$ comverges.

Comment: While the above is true, it doesn't really use the hypothesis fully as we are given for example that $f_n(1) = f(1)$, where $f_n(z), f(z)$ are the series in question regarded as analytic functions on the unit disc with continuous extension to the boundary and it applies very generally; the hypothesis implies $f_n(z)$ converges locally uniformly to $f(z)$ inside the disc and weakly on the boundary so for example $f_n, f$ analytic on the full disc or even $f_n$ uniformly of bounded variation ( equivalent to derivatives of $f_n$ have uniformly bounded $H^1$ norm) implies the conclusion too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the result holds. Sketch: In fact as $n\to \infty,$

$$\tag 1 \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|a_{mn}-a_m| \to 0,$$

which implies the result.

Elementary approach: To prove $(1),$ start with this: Given $\epsilon>0,$ there exists $M$ such that $\sum_{m=1}^{M}a_m >C-\epsilon;$ argue that therefore $\sum_{m=1}^{M}a_{mn} >C-2\epsilon$ for large $n.$

Measure theory approach: Suppose $f_1,f_2,\dots \in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ a.e. If $\int |f_n|\to \int |f|,$ then $\int|f_n-f| \to 0.$ This result is well known and has appeared on MSE a zillion times; it involves a slightly clever use of Fatou's lemma. In your problem we would be working in $l^1(\mathbb N).$

Comment: For the first claim, why for given $\epsilon >0$, $n_{\epsilon}$, doesn't go to infinity with $n$? If you can show that doesn't happen obviously you are done, but there is no uniformity in $n$ apriori.

Comment: @Conrad For each $m,$ $a_{mn}\to a_m.$ Once $M$ is found for $\sum a_m$, we only have finitely many $m$ to worry about, which gives uniformity in $n.$ I rewrote it to make this clearer.

Comment: why? $a_{mn}$ can oscillate around $a_m$ - e.g $a_m = \frac{1}{m^2}$, while $a_{mn} = 0$ for n up to $exp(exp(exp(m))))$ and very slowly converging to $a_m$ for a fixed $m$, while to keep the sum fixed you just need to make one $a_{m(n)n}$ big enough for each $n$ and some $m(n)$ - so in other words given a double sequence $a_{mn}$, you can modify it by dropping finitely many $a_{mn}$ (depending on $n$), add/subtract any function that goes to zero with $n$ (as long as this keeps the coefficients positive, the sum in $m$ less than $C$ for each $n$ and compensate with one early term for each $n$

Comment: @Conrad   For $m=1,2,\dots ,M$ there exists $N_m$ such that $a_{mn}>a_m-\epsilon/M$ for $n\ge N_m.$ Let $N= \max (N_1,\dots, N_M).$ Then $n\ge N$ gives

$$ \sum_{m=1}^{M}a_{mn} > \sum_{m=1}^{M}(a_{m}-\epsilon/M) > C-\epsilon - \epsilon = C-2\epsilon.$$

So I should have $C-2\epsilon$ as the lower bound. I'll fix that, but I don't think that was what you were worried about.

Comment: Yes, agree, argument is correct due to positivity